# Out-Gridview even if no data found

Tags: powershell, out-gridview

I have an out-gridview implemented in my powershell script which shows me all files today created.
If there are files in the specific path it works fine but if not nothing happens.

It would be great that the grid appears even if the directory doesn't contain any files. Either the grid lists no items or just maybe a notification that no files have been found.

example:

```
gci C:\User\Executions\2018-01-25 | Out-GridView
```

Everything would be nicer than nothing :-)

Sure, I could use Test-Path to query and write anywhere (e.g. Write-Host) but it is more aesthetic to output the message in a grid.

Comment: Put your query into a variable, test if it exists, else, `'Message' | OGV`

Comment: That's the solution!!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
$list = Get-ChildItem "C:\User\Executions\2018-01-25"
if(($list).count -gt 0){
  Get-ChildItem $list | Out-GridView
}else{
  'No Data found' | Out-GridView
}
```

@TheIncorrigible1 thank you!

Comment: You could further simplify this. `$List = Get-ChildItem 'C:\User\Executions\2018-01-25'; If ($List) { $List | Out-GridView } Else { 'No Data found' | Out-GridView }`

Comment: This way, you don't need to query the entire directory twice.

Comment: *thumbs up* !! @TheIncorrigible1

Comment: As far as simplifying goes, you could go one further and use -OutVariable inside the If command's conditional and ultimately remove your first command (assigning a value to $List). See my example.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone beat me to it, but I'll include my example as well. Mine uses services, however. On my machine, if the Get-Service command uses -Name s*, it'll open Out-GridView with the services that begin with S. If the Get-Service command uses -Name x*, it'll run the Else portion and open Out-GridView with the PSCustomObject. What this version does give you is the ability to label the column. In Danijel de Vasco's example it uses a default of "string" as the column header vs. mine, which uses "Message." More or less the same thing, however, with a minor customization.

```
If (Get-Service -Name s* -OutVariable Services) {
    $Services | Out-GridView
} Else {
    $Message = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Message = 'No Files Found'
    }
    $Message | Out-GridView
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am feeling generous today

```
try
{
    $out = gci C:\User\Executions\2018-01-25
    if ($out)
    {
        $out | Out-GridView
    }
    else
    {
        $null = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Directory is empty", "Notification", "OK", "Information")
    }
}
catch
{
    $ErrMsg = $_.Exception.Message
    $null = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Error Occurred: $ErrMsg", "Error", "OK", "Error")
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add the type in order to use `[MessageBox]`

Comment: [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox] did u mean this? It is added.

Comment: this works fine - thank you @Rohin Sidharth.
Thank you for being generous :-)

Comment: Not in your codeblock.  You need `Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework` in your snippet before calling `[System.Windows.MessageBox]`